# Query for transforming from row to column doesn't work

Tags: mysql, view, pivot

Reading discussions having as topic pivot table I didn't get the solution, so I hope this time I get through this issue.

I have the table mg_postmeta with these columns

```
Post_ID | meta_key | meta value|
--------|----------|-----------|
001     |  sku     |  a00b     |
001     |  price   |  200      |
002     |  sku     |  b001     |
002     |  price   |  120      |
```

that I would to reorganize in this way with the possibility to update it frequently

```
Post_ID |  sku     | price     |
--------|----------|-----------|
001     |  a00b    |  200      |
002     |  b001    |  120      |
```

As suggested in other similar posts, seems that the solution is to have a pivot table and they provided the following query that I changed according my fields:

```
SELECT
    post_id, 
    SUM(mg_postmeta.meta_key = '_store')AS SKU,
    SUM(mg_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price')AS RegPrice

FROM mg_postmeta

WHERE post_id=13229

GROUP BY post_id
```

As result, instead of having the expected values, I got 1 in SKU and 0 in RegPrice that is not the expected result.

Furhtermore, since it is for a frequent update use, what could be the optimal solution? Query, View or Table?

Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this is the solution I got after several tests

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price,
   MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku
FROM mg_posts p LEFT JOIN mg_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID)                 
WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title
```

it generates exactly what was expected.